# Единое подключение к БД в программе

Tags: c#, mysql

Грубо говоря, есть программа на С#, которая работает с MySQL. Возможно ли сделать общее подключение к БД и использовать его во всех функциях программы, а не подключаться к БД из каждой функции?

Comment: Можно вынести работу с БД в отдельный класс, в котором подключение к БД будет происходить всего один раз при старте программы или перед первым запросом.

Comment: Это не такая хорошая идея как кажется - ведь в случае потери связи с сервером восстановить подключение будет довольно сложно.

Comment: Этот отдельный класс по каким-то причинам не сможет автоматически переподключиться?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите это сделать для улучшения производительности - не делайте этого.

Чисто физически, вы не переподключаетесь к БД из "всех функций". MySQL Connector, как и классы для работы с MS SQL, поддерживают механизм Connection Pooling. Они сами поддерживают некоторое количество открытых физических соединений. При "открытии" соединения из кода вы получаете готовое заранее открытое соединение. При "закрытии" - возвращаете его обратно в pool. Новое соединение реально открывается только в случае, если все свободных соединений в pool не осталось.

Т.е. методы Open/Close на самом деле просто отмечают соединение как "используемое кем-то в данный момент". И без такой "отметки" работать было бы довольно проблематично - т.к. ни MySQL, ни MS SQL (без включенного режима MARS) не умеют в одном соединении выдавать два одновременных результата. Т.е. любая мелочь - незакрытый `DataReader`, незакрытая транзакция, неудачно закрытая транзакция - и ваше "общее" соединение окажется в совершенно непредсказуемом состоянии.

Как только вы выбрасываете стандартный механизм - вы вынуждены писать свой набор костылей для стабилизации и переоткрытия соединения.

Если вы хотите сделать это для упрощения кода - надоело вам каждый раз писать `using`/`Open` - сделайте метод, который принимает параметром текст команды и Dictionary с параметрами. И возвращает `int` или `DataSet`.

А еще лучше - используйте ORM, а не вызывайте SQL напрямую.